# How do you turn a string thats in a array into a class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

I'm trying to turn a string that's in an array into a class this isn't the exact code but I would like to know how to do this

```
var classes = ["({x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100})", "({x: 10, y: 10, width: 70, height: 70})"];
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length;i++) {
   var c = new window[classes[i]];
   console.log(c.width);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the syntax you provided in your `classes` variable, you can't do the simplest (and safest) method `JSON.parse()` because your string doesn't match the [JSON Syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_syntax.htm).

You could also achieve this with `eval()` function. Which is native in JavaScript:

```js
let classes = ["({x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100})", "({x: 10, y: 10, width: 70, height: 70})"],
    objects = []
objects = classes.map((c)=> eval(c))
console.log(objects)
```

> ***Note:*** I would definetly not recommend this, since you must have a very strict control of the origin of the string. Otherwise, this method could cause a several vulnerability in your application.

Comment: Thanks the results perfect, Is there a safer way though?

Comment: @RonanLeonard Nothing to thank, glad to help! The safest method for this would be using `JSON.parse()`. Since doing: `JSON.parse("alert(/vulnerable/)")` won't work. But try: `eval("alert(/vulnerable/)")`, that's why you must make sure the origin of the string is safe. You should not let the user place his own strings inside an `eval()` function.

Answer (score -1):

`JSON.parse()` can convert a JSON string to an object. For instance

```
JSON.parse("{'width':100, 'height':200}")
```

will return a javascript object.

Comment: This doesn't solve user's question. `JSON.parse()` wont parse the string since its identifiers (as provided in his example) aren't using double quotes.